# Работа с переменными

Tags: java

У меня возникла необходимость работы с несколькими переменными с однотипными названиями, хотел бы узнать, можно ли программно задать "индекс" переменной и работать с ней. Возможно, вопрос задал чуть не конкретно, сам не знаю, как можно это описать словами, вот пример:

Я имею несколько переменных: s1, s2, s3... , названия у всех однотипны. Можно ли обращаться не к каждой по отдельности, а сделать это через цикл какой-нибудь? Что-то типа:

```
for (int i=1; i=...; i++){
    s[i]=...
}
```

Я понимаю, что это неверно, может это можно реализовать через массив? Переменные типа TextView (Android). Спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 1):

Массивы в Java создаются следующим образом:

```
TextView[] s = new TextView[5]; // Объявление и создание массива в памяти
```

Вместо `TextView`, разумеется, может быть какой-либо другой тип.